# getting permission denied error when trying to run mix release

Tags: permissions, elixir, release, permission-denied, elixir-mix

I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/jonlunsford/deploying-elixir-1-of-3-building-releases-with-mix-1o4a) and created a build with few modifications. After generating a build with dockerfile, when I try to run the release I get permission denied error.

**Context**:

- Trying to generate release with docker file and put tar release back in _build folder so I can upload to server and run
- The build was successful and [here is code, I tried](https://github.com/tanweerdev/build_permission)

**Steps to reproduce on sample project**:

- git clone https://github.com/tanweerdev/build_permission
- cd into project
- mix deps.get
- mix docker.build prod
- _build/prod/rel/my_build/bin/my_build start_iex

and you will get permission denied error

**BUT** if you try with sudo, it works. I dont know why permissions gets changed. Any help why we need sudo? or is it a good solution to change permission after build is generated?

Comment: The issue is obviously with a custom `docker.build` task, that produces the release file with incorrect permissions. What host OS do you use in the first place to build?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Thanks @AlekseiMatiushkin . How can I fix it? I am not touching permission inside this custom task.